# Insert associative array in table with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: database, laravel-4, insert, eloquent

how do I insert with Laravel Eloquent an associative array

I have this array

```
$data =  array (
  0 => 
    array (
      'first_id' => string '52763718329' 
      'second_id' => string '222122'
  ),
  1 => 
    array(
      'first_id' => string '527628573' (length=9)
      'second_id' => string '22210' (length=5)
   )
);

$model = new MyModel;
//$model->$data how do I pus data array?
$model->save();
```

Comment: Using `insert` method

Comment: okay but is there a way to not loop over the array, jut simply give the array of more records? I'm just lookin on this documentation http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete but I do not find

Comment: `DB::table(..)->insert([ your array of arrays ]);` - it's single `INSERT` statement, no looping over arrays. It's also prefered way for inserting multiple rows in terms of performance.  However it doesn't use any Eloquent features, like `timestamps` etc, so you need to take care of that.

Comment: So Eloquent does not have such a method? Because of data valiadation would good to have it

Comment: Yeah, like I said it's not Eloquent, but underlying `Query\Builder`. You can't run single query, nor can you do that without loop using ORM. Btw data validation doesn't belong to the ORM model, despite Ardent and stuff.

Comment: is true I checked! than I go with Laravels DB

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $data->ToArray();

DB::table('mytable')->insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Laravel 5 says it can handle multiple array but never seems to work.

A simple solution is to just loop and do an insert with a foreach.

```
foreach($data as $insert){ 
            $id = \DB::table('tablename')->insertGetId($insert);

        }
```

You can also wrap it in a transaction so if one of the items fail they roll everything back.

```
//transaction start
\DB::beginTransaction();

foreach($data as $insert){ 
         $id = \DB::table('tablename')->insertGetId($insert);
         if(empty($id){    
            Log::error('Failed to insert row into database.');
            \DB::rollback();
            break;
   }
 }
//save everything
\DB::commit();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Its Work very well in Laravel 5 
if you have an Arry for example 

> item_array_m = array('name'=>'jhon','surname'=>'Doe');

In Eloquent the insert Query is save(); to insert in this way 

>  public function store(item_array_m)
>     {
>         var_dump($item_array_m);
>         $flight = new Carrito;
> 
>         $flight->name = $item_array_m["name"];     
>         $flight->surname = $item_array_m["surname"];
>  
> 
>         $flight->save();
>     }
```